# php facebook post messsage to feed with link returns an error, but the is post is visible on facebook

Tags: php, facebook

When you create a post array, it works like expected, however when i specify he link property, facebook returns the "Unsupported post request."

Has anybody seen this behaviour ? is this a known bug ? or more importantly, how do i get a valid id. ? I'm using the php facebook api.

Below works ;

```
message : 11111111111
name    : 2222222222
description : 333333333333
picture : https://free-cupones.com/images/tmp/h8kt1h3fkspgit5tveh0gi38k4/10430383_10152426393219471_471593300264201727_n.jpg
caption : 4444444444444444
access_token : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...

$postResult = $facebook->api("/" .  $pageId . "/feed" , "post",  $arrPost );
```

This works not and returns the error;

```
message : 11111111111
name    : 2222222222
description : 333333333333
link      : example.com
picture : https://free-cupones.com/images/tmp/h8kt1h3fkspgit5tveh0gi38k4/10430383_10152426393219471_471593300264201727_n.jpg
caption : 4444444444444444
access_token : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...

$postResult = $facebook->api("/" .  $pageId . "/feed" , "post",  $arrPost );
```

Answer (score 1):

... Facebook has fixed the bug, it is in the beta stage, but will be pushed live in the next couple of days

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/726825557390253

Answer (score 0):

You might be having similar issues as [Facebook PHP SDK - Getting error when posting to facebook page but post is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483120/facebook-php-sdk-getting-error-when-posting-to-facebook-page-but-post-is-creat)

Is your app publicly visible? You can check in the status area of your app dashboard at http://developers.facebook.com.

Comment: Yea, it is public. I reported it to facebook and they have assigned the bug. 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/726825557390253

Comment: But indeed, i have seen many bugs going around that look like this one, it feels like fb has a big issue there, but they know about it since januari, the fb engineers keep asking for more info and are not able to recreate the bug... 

My workaround is simple.. post the message, do a read of the feed from the last x messages when you get this specific error with a non empty link in the message, then compare each post with the message send. This way you can at least extract the id of the post you just made.

Comment: It's definitely an annoying issue.  I'll try using the workaround you suggest, cheers!